# Разница с www и без него

Tags: apache, веб-программирование, домен

В чем разница между
    www.example.com

и
    example.com

Она очевидно есть, потому как иначе смысл так делать

Comment: Разница для сео только есть, а так по желанию, можно с www можно и без. Можно другой написать сабдомен

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@vkovalchuk88](/users/13851/vkovalchuk88) правильно написал. Только в СЕО играет роль с www и без. Это уже дело хозяйское что выбирать. И если сайт крутится, то обязательно нужно выбрать что-то одно: или c www или без www. Иначе поисковая система посчитает сайты http://site.ru и http://www.site.ru как 2 разных сайта, соответсвенно это дубль контента и попадание под фильтр поисковиков.

Answer (score 0):

помню времена, когда надо было писать обязательно эти www, иначе не уходил бы на сайт (это еще когда интернет начинал приходить к нам), тогда еще были интранеты. И на данный момент кроме СЕО не должно ни на что влиять.

А вообще, слышал новость, что в РФ хотят создать "закрытую" сеть от внешнего мира, подобие интернета. :)